# Concat strings with different amount of values

Tags: database, concatenation, fill

I am having five strings with a different amount of RangeIndex. String 1 for example could have the following data:

```
20160101   1.08526
20160102   1.08535
20160103   1.09052
20160104   1.08659
```

String 2 is as follows

```
20160101   150.0659
20160103   145.8063
20160104   143.5892
```

with the normal concat function I would get the following result

```
20160101   1.08526 20160101 150.0659
20160102   1.08535 20160103 145.8063
20160103   1.09052 20160104 143.5892
20160104   1.08659
```

The result I am looking for should be as follow

```
20160101   1.08526 20160101 150.0659
20160102   1.08535 20160102 150.0659
20160103   1.09052 20160103 145.8063
20160104   1.08659 20160104 143.5892
```

This means that the combination of the two strings should put the right data together with the right date. If there is an empty field the system should chose the previous value to fill the gap.

How can that be done?

Comment: is this in a tables within a database you'd use SQL in or not a database at all?  if a database what version and type (oracle, MSSQL etc?)

Comment: These are simple csv files. No database involved